# Mysql : find nearest Maximum value, if not find nearest minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having db structure like this -

> Table : Tasks
>
> Columns:
> TaskID, TaskDescription, TaskCreatedDate

So if I want to find `TaskCreatedDate` having nearest greater value to current timestamp, and if there is no any task present having greater value than current timestamp then find `TaskCreatedDate` having nearest smaller value to current timestamp. This should done in single query. How can I do this?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you tried before? It can help us. Thanks.

Comment: Is TaskCreatedDate is a date time field?

Comment: How would you arrange something to have a created date greater than the current timestamp?

Comment: I tried with Min(), Max() functions but it gives me both values i.e. nearest smaller and nearest greater. I just want nearest greater and if that is not present then nearest smaller.

Comment: By mistake I gave TaskCreatedDate, actually this is TaskDueDate.

Comment: @FrancoisM - Yes this date time field used for setting task due date

Comment: Why sometimes you ll want max or min value? The value is not there always?

Answer (score 1):

```
-- IN ONE GO
select t.*, coalesce( (select TaskCreatedDate from Tasks where TaskCreatedDate > t.TaskCreatedDate ORDER BY TaskCreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1),
                      (select TaskCreatedDate from Tasks where TaskCreatedDate < t.TaskCreatedDate ORDER BY TaskCreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
            )
  from Tasks as t
```

coalesce allow us to return second condition when first is null

Answer (score 0):

As we do not have a piece of code to to well understand, you can try:

```
select      *
from        Tasks 
order by    cast([TaskDueDate] as datetime) asc
```

**CAST** or **CONVERT** convert explicit a value form one data type to another.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a clever `order by` clause:

```
select *
from tasks
order by  TaskCreatedDate > now() desc,
         (case when TaskCreatedDate > now() then TaskCreatedDate end) asc,
         (case when TaskCreatedDate < now() then TaskCreatedDate end) desc
limit 1;
```

Depending on how your types are defined, you might want to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `now()`.

The first clause in the order by orders future dates first, then past dates.  The second puts the future dates in order by TaskCreatedDate in ascending order, so the closest one is first.  If there are none, then the third comes into play, ordering the rest descending.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a union of the first later-than-now task (if any), plus the last earlier-than-now task, and keep the first result.

```
(select TaskId, TaskDescription, TaskDueDate from Tasks
        where TaskDueDate >= now() 
        order by TaskDueDate
        limit 1)
union
(select TaskId, TaskDescription, TaskDueDate from Tasks
        where TaskDueDate < now() 
        order by TaskDueDate desc
        limit 1)
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT *
FROM Tasks
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN TIMEDIFF(TaskDueDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 
    (CASE WHEN TIMEDIFF(TaskDueeDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) > 0
        THEN TIMEDIFF (TaskDueeDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
        ELSE TIMEDIFF (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), TaskDueDate)
     END)
```

That will give you all the tasks with future due dates, ordered by increasing date, followed by those with due dates in the past ordred by decreasing date. If you only want one task, add `LIMIT 1` at the end